# Remove old artist in FuncAnimation of Matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, cartopy, satellite

I am creating an animation on a cartopy map. 
The map shows the satellite orbit the earth with interval = 1s. 
In my code, I added satellite on the map using AnnotationBbox class and add_artist method as the code below. 
The problem is every 1 second, the map updates a new satellite without removing the old one so it makes a streak on the map as the picture (below the code). How can I fix this ? Thank you so much for your help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as crs
import cartopy
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, OffsetImage
from PIL import Image
from skyfield.api import EarthSatellite, Topos, load
import time
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
###############################################################################

# Get information of satellite
line1 = '1 25544U 98067A   14020.93268519  .00009878  00000-0  18200-3 0  5082'
line2 = '2 25544  51.6498 109.4756 0003572  55.9686 274.8005 15.49815350868473'

satellite = EarthSatellite(line1, line2, name='ISS (ZARYA)')

# cartopy map
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
ax = plt.axes(projection=crs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=.5)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAKES, alpha=0.95)
ax.coastlines()
ax.stock_img()

# Read satellite image
img = Image.open('sat.png')
ax.set_global()

#####################################################################

def animate(i): 

    # Get coordinate of satellite every 1 second
    ts = load.timescale()
    t = ts.now()
    geometry = satellite.at(t)
    subpoint = geometry.subpoint()
    lat = subpoint.latitude.degrees
    lon = subpoint.latitude.degrees

    # Add satellite on the cartopy map
    imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.03)
    imagebox.image.axes = ax
    ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, [lat, lon], pad=0, frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
    return ax

ani = FuncAnimation(ax.figure,
                    animate,
                    frames=10000,
                    interval=1000, blit=False, repeat=False) 

plt.show()
```

[image: streak on the map]

Comment: `def animate(i): plt.cla() ...`I think it would be good to add this to the code.

Comment: plt.cla() delete my background map, only keep satellite

Answer (score 1):

They way you have that structured means it's adding a new `OffsetImage` and `AnnotationBbox` to the plot every second. The way `FuncAnimation` is intended to be used is that you should just be adjusting the underlying data (like the position) of relevant parts of the plot. Something like this should work:

```
imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.03)
imagebox.image.axes = ax
ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, [0, 0], pad=0, frameon=False)
ax.add_artist(ab)

def animate(i): 
    # Get coordinate of satellite every 1 second
    ts = load.timescale()
    t = ts.now()
    geometry = satellite.at(t)
    subpoint = geometry.subpoint()
    lat = subpoint.latitude.degrees
    lon = subpoint.latitude.degrees
    ab.xy = [lon, lat]
    return ab,

ani = FuncAnimation(ax.figure,
                    animate,
                    frames=10000,
                    interval=1000, blit=False, repeat=False) 

plt.show()
```